# jQuery insertBefore(':first', object) vs prependTo(object)

Tags: jquery

Forgive me for being stupid, but are these two effectively the same?

The only reason I ask is I've seen the former in a plugin I'm adapting, and I was a little thrown by the fact it wasn't simply using `prependTo()` instead;

```
$('li:last', list)
    .clone()
    .insertBefore( $('li:first', list) );
```

### Update

Following on from my initial question, and concerning @Nick's comments regarding cloning, would these two scenarios produce the same outcome?

```
// 1
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    $('li:first', list)
        .clone()
        .insertAfter( $('li:last', list) );
    $('li:first', list).remove();
}

// 2
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    $('li:first', list).appendTo(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they would accomplish the same thing, as long as you're cloning in both cases..otherwise it would move the element.

Comment: Thanks for putting my doubts to rest! And +1 for the tip concerning cloning.

Comment: Made a little addition to my question.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - the result in your updated question is not the same, the moved one with `.appendTo()` would keep event handlers and data...the other `.clone()` (it's not `.clone(true)`) would lose them.

Comment: Thanks Nick, yeah I noticed this when put in practice - other than that, the DOM effect is the same.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the usage.

insertBefore() literally inserts an element **before** an element whereas prependTo() inserts an element at the **beginning** (but within) an element.

In your case, `$('li:last', list).clone().insertBefore( $('li:first', list) );` will insert the last element before the first li element.

If you were to use `$('li:last', list).clone().prependTo( $('li:first', list) );`, the last li element would be added *inside* of the first li element, which you dont want. To use prependTo() in the same manner as insertBefore, you would need to do 
`$('li:last', list).clone().prependTo( $(list) );` (assuming *list* is a reference to the UL tag.)

Comment: Thanks @simshaun, I was aware of the differences, I was just unsure if the *particular* usage of said methods had different outcomes :)